# values exist in data.table in multiple columns R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table

```
dt <- data.table(c(1,2,3,4),c("chr1","chr1","chr2","chr3"),c(12,12,13,14))
```

This is just an example data frame, but in real I have million of rows with three columns.
I need to find if a set of value exists in it or not.
Example, I want to check if "chr1" in column 2 and "2" in column exist together?

I was using `"chr1" %in% dt$V2`, but dont know how to combine two value criteria and make it fast for millions of row.

Comment: May be `dt[, V1==2 & V2=='chr1']#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE`

Comment: I need something faster search, as there are millions of row and it takes around 4 sec to search.

Comment: `==` should be faster than `%in%` for a single value comparison.  I am not sure whether pasting the two columns together and comparing would be faster though.

Comment: I have setkeys(dt,"V1","V2"). but not sure how can i use this to increase the speed

Comment: @user1631306 `dt[J(2, 'chr1')]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `data.table`, we can use both a) traditional vector-scan approach (what base-R and dplyr's filter does), and b) use *binary search* which is incredibly faster than (a).

```
require(data.table)
setkey(dt, V1, V2)
dt[J(2, "chr1"), nomatch=0L] # by default nomatch=NA
```

`nomatch=NA` returns NA when no matches are there, and `nomatch=0L` returns only those rows that match.

Setting keys on a `data.table` sorts by those columns (and sets the attribute `sorted`). This helps to use `binary search` on the data, that searches your query in `O(log n)` time complexity (on average), as opposed to a vector scan approach that has O(n) complexity (since it has to scan through *all the rows*). It also needs a logical vector the size of the number of rows in your data.

What @akrun and @rrs have shown are examples of vector scan approaches using `data.table` and `dplyr`, respectively. And @eddi has shown you (repeated here in this answer) the binary search approach using `data.table`.

This is particularly useful if you're wanting to subset multiple times.

In the next versions of `data.table`, we're trying to get this speed-up happen internally with the normal vector scan syntax. Matt's implemented it, and testing it. If and when that comes out, you can use the usual vector scan syntax, and internally, `data.table` will use the binary search approach. That'd a great feature, I think you'd agree ;).

Comment: Thats really fast, but it returns me the row (in any case, the values exist or not). Though the third column would be NA, if value doesn't exist. I can use this to turn it into TRUE or FALSE, but is there any clean solution to it?

Comment: I've edited the use of `nomatch` argument in `data.table`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I was looking for simple TRUE or FALSE return. But I guess, I can use "NA" easily. Thanks for your help

Comment: @user1631306 `as.logical(nrow(DT[J(2, "chr1"), nomatch=0L]))` does the trick.